# Looking for a BAMS text about the group with commutation relations defined using meaningful words

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, recreational-mathematics, linguistics

What I definitely remember is that I saw a description of the following in the Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, sometime in eighties (or maybe nineties?)

One considers the group generated by letters of the Latin alphabet, with the following relations: $W(a,b,...,y,z)=W'(a,b,...,y,z)$ for any words that are permutations of each other and moreover each of them is a meaningful word in English. For example, $name=mane=mean=amen$ in this group.

The question was whether this group is commutative.

Does anybody remember it? Or maybe knows the answer?

**Slightly later**

Neil Strickland points out that it is Monthly (1986) rather than BAMS.
So formally he answered the question, except that there is another thing I did remember incorrectly: the question there was what is the center of this group!

So, what is the center of this group?

Comment: For a minute motivation: all relators are trivial in the abelianization, and therefore the abelianization map is the obvious one $p:G_{\mathrm{English}}\to\mathbf{Z}^{26}$, and the question is whether the surjective map $p$ is bijective.

Comment: Does Q commute with U?

Comment: Are you sure you are not thinking of Quotients homophones des groupes libres (Homophonic quotients of free groups) by Jean-François Mestre, René Schoof, Lawrence Washington, and Don Zagier?

Comment: @DanPetersen The paper that you mention cites https://doi.org/10.2307/2322324 which is in the Monthly (1986) and is probably what მამუკაჯიბლაძე is thinking of.  That document does not contain any proofs; it remarks that $G$ is probably not abelian, asks what the centre might be.

Comment: (Paging @StevenLandsburg, who wrote the thing that I mentioned.)

Comment: @NeilStrickland That's it, definitely! Seems like memory played a trick on me, I was absolutely sure it was BAMS and much earlier than that, but at the same time I remember clearly that detail about the enormous $26\times26$ chart...

Comment: The work (seems to be from 2015) referred to from the following article shows that the quotient is actually trivial under an alternate set of (not completely unreasonable) relations: https://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2015/oct/29/mathematicians-prove-the-triviality-of-english

Comment: @DanPetersen Note that the paper you suggest answers a different question. Actually I remembered the one in my question when re-reading (for pleasure) the one you suggest. If I only knew that it contains the answer to my question in references!

Comment: @auniket That one is about a different question related to pronunciation, investigated in the paper that Dan Petersen mentions.

Comment: @NeilStrickland No sorry why earlier? 1986 is early enough, don't know why I thought otherwise. It is definitely this one that I saw, I only confused the journal. Will modify the question accordingly.

Comment: I think that if you want a definitive answer then you should specify a dictionary.  For example, I used /usr/dict/words, but that contains all element names (He, Li, Be etc) which creates a lot of commutativity.

Comment: @NeilStrickland In that text you pointed out, Landsburg proposes to take Webster.

Comment: Indeed.  But I don't think you'll get a answer unless you specify a dictionary that is readily available as a flat text file.

Answer (score 5):

I checked that in `/usr/dict/words` there are a handful of words in which q appears without a following u, but none of them are free of repetition and have any anagrams.  This means that we have a surjective homomorphism to the free group $\langle q,u\rangle$ sending all other letters to the identity, so $q$ and $u$ do not commute, as Jeremy suggested.

[UPDATE] My original answer assumed that we were only using words with no repeated letters, in which case Jeremy's comment would not be applicable.  I now see that this restriction is not in fact in the original problem.  Nonetheless, I have now run a brute-force check including words with repeated letters and reached the same conclusion.  If you take any word that possesses anagrams and map it to $\langle q,u\rangle$ you get either a power of $u$ or the element $qu$.

Comment: Couldn't we have something like "uquit" and "quitu" (I know they're not actually words), together with other relations implying that "it" commutes with "u"?

Comment: If proper names are allowed, there is Huq which might be used somehow (don't know how, though).

Comment: @JeremyRickard Googling gives https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-containing-uqu where one finds "tuque", "bouquet", "chibouque", among others

Comment: There are various words like these, but they are not really relevant here unless they have at least one nontrivial anagram, which seems unlikely.

Comment: Hmmm, apparently an **umiaq** is an Inuit boat, and **maqui** is a kind of wineberry. And don't get me started on **equinus** and **uniques** or **equus** and **usque**!

Comment: @JeremyRickard OK, you win!